# Does TYPO3 has any advanced API to handle FlexForms manipulations?

Tags: api, typo3

Does TYPO3 (or probably some developer extensions) proposes some API helpers to get / set values for FlexForms XML, which are used in plugins configurations (BE/eID usage also) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at flux, an extbase-extension http://fedext.net/examples/flux/features.html

Pros:
- Write FlexForms in fluid
- Dynamic reloading of parts of forms when something changes
- Abitity to hook into load/save of flexform values and do additional processing

Cons:
- Needs fed, which is huge and overkill if you just want a better way to dealing with flexforms
- For me, at least, it had some bugs

However, even if you do not use it, it makes sense to download it and have a look at the code. You can learn a lot about how T3 handles FlexForms internally and perhaps come up with a simpler way to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. This approach looks very interesting. If I understood correctly, it will not help to deal with flexforms of other extensions.

Comment: No, if you want to hook into the flexform processing of a plugin whose code you do not control, all you have is the flexform-save/load-hooks.

Answer (score 3):

For the moment, the easiest way I found to manipulate TYPO3 flexforms (plugin configuration in my case) is following snippet :

```
$flexformArray = t3lib_div::xml2array($flexformXml);
// Data manipulation here ...
$flexObj = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_flexformtools');
$xml = $flexObj->flexArray2Xml($flexformArray, true);
```

So, we are obliged to pass by PHP array to make modifications in XML data.

If somebody proposes better way, You are welcome to share it.

Answer (score 0):

From TYPO3 v8 its done with

```
$flexformArray = GeneralUtility::xml2array($row['pi_flexform']);

// data manipulation like
$flexformArray['data']['additional']['lDEF']['settings.limit']['vDEF'] = 5;

// convert array back to flexformXML
$flexObj = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FlexFormTools::class);
$flexFormXml = $flexObj->flexArray2Xml($flexformArray, true);
```